# Hibernate: unable to save object using JPA when object is containing reference of saved object

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

I have an employer table with schema containing userprofileId

The employer table as stated below is containing userprofileid which is primary key of user table

```
id                 int(11)      (not NULL)         PRI        
userprofileid      int(11)      (not nUll)                          
organization_name  varchar(50)  (not nUll)
```

Now my requirement was create a JPA class for this employer.

Now we have Employer.java, with below entry.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="userProfileId", referencedColumnName="id" )
    @Column( insertable=false ,updatable =false)
    private UserProfile userProfile;

    @Column(name = "organization_name")
    private String organizationName;
```

Now hurdle is.
Our UserProfile is object is created in different method. Now i dont want to again add same  value to userprofile table and so i made insertable = false and updatable = false in employer.java so that the field does not get updated;

No if i set the value of userprofile in employer object

it says

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.hcentive.core.user.UserProfile; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.hcentive.core.user.UserProfile
```

but if i dont set the user profile it gives below error.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'userprofileid' doesn't have a default value
```

Note for persisting I am using :

```
getJpaTemplate().persist(t);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Employer refers to an already existing user profile. If it already exists, it is in the database. If it is in the database, you must not create a new instance, but get it from the database. To get something from the database, you use the `EntityManager.find()` or `EntityManager.getReference()` method (the second one doesn't even do any select statement).

So, remove the `insertable` and `updatable` flags from your annotation (the association **is** insertable), and use code similar to the following one:

```
UserProfile up = em.getReference(UserProfile.class, userProfileId);
employer.setUserProfile(up);
em.persist(employer);
```